# Manually Assign a GitLab Project (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab

I want to use the GitLab VS Code Extension with a private project.

I added my account, generated the token and saved it in VsCode.

When I click on the extension I can see the name of my project but it's marked as "no gitLab project".

When I right click on it, I can select "Manually Assign a GitLab Project" and then I have a textbox to fill. I tried with the local path of my project (where the .git file is), I tried with the link I use in the browser to get to my project and the link I use to  clone it, but I always get "Cannot find project with path ..."

What's the right way of setting my project?

Comment: I am in the same situation, same problem! Did you find a solution how to solve it? The response of sqoor leads basically to the same situation => "(no GitLab project"

Comment: @Perino still the same problem (17/08/2023)

Answer (score 2):

You can sign out and sign back in by clicking the [Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8NnH.png) icon on the bottom left corner. It worked for me

Comment: In my opinion, this is the most optimal answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue tyring to connect with , I have linked vsCode to GitLab with following steps:

1. On vsCode `CMD + P` , type: `> Gitlab: Add Account to VS Code`
   [image]
2. Add URL to Gitlab instance: it is not necessarily `https://gitlab.com`, it could be something different, like for example `https://gitlab.company-name.com/` (IMPORTANT to put the right link)
   [image]
3. Paste your GitLab personal Access Token
   [image]
4. In case you do not have an access token yet, just go here `https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens` or `https://gitlab.xxxxx.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens` and create new access token, you just need api & api_user that's the default, you can add more premissions if you need, put the expiration time to next month, year or whatever date in the future

[image]

Then you suppose to see the project(s) in your gitlab account on vscode.